# Using FFImageloading RoundedTranformation for dynamic fields.

Tags: xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

Hi I want to apply RoundedTransformation to dynamically created CachedImage in XamarinForms.

here is code for dynamic creation of CachedImage

```
var imgProd = new CachedImage { Source = temp.imgSource, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, Margin = 0, DownsampleHeight = vm.featureStackHeight, DownsampleToViewSize = true, Aspect = Aspect.Fill};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just go:

```
imgProd.Transformations.Add(new CircleTransformation());
```